# Import/Export (Azure) Databricks Notebooks programatically

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have a databricks notebook that takes as an input the location of the table and then generates graphs.

I can run this notebook from a wrapper notebook for many different tables.

Is it possible that every time that the notebook run, I save it with the results as an html in the databricks files system.

In essence, I want to programmatically export the notebook, in the same way as I would manually do File>Export>HTML

Is that possible? if yes, how?

Note: I was thinking that ,if there is nothing out of the box, I guess that the notebooks will be saved somewhere internally in the driver. I could get it from there and move it where I want with dbutils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN general you can export notebook using either REST API, via the [`export` endpoint](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#export) of workspace API - you [can specify that you want to export as HTML](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#notebookexportformat).  Another option is to use [`workspace export` command](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html) of the Databricks CLI that uses REST API under the hood, but it's easier to use.

But in your case, the notebook (most probably, if you use `dbutils.notebook.run`) is executed as a separate job, so you need to use [Runs Export API instead](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#jobsjobsserviceexportrun).

To call the API you need to have personal access token and host name, but it's easy to retrieve it programmatically from inside of the notebook.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717633/logging-attached-cluster-information-in-databricks-spark/66196550#66196550) for exact details.

P.S.  Notebook is not an object on file system, or something like - it exists only in memory, and not available on driver node.  Maybe it will change with the upcoming [Repos feature](https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html).

Comment: Yes, I started exploring the DatabricksApi (https://pypi.org/project/databricksapi/)

I made some progress, and I believe it almost done. I will update when it is ready.

Thanks for your info :)

Comment: this is unofficial package.  You may consider installing the `databricks-cli` package, and use it as SDK (really it has SDK inside)

Comment: I will explore that option too, lets see what works best.

Answer (score 0):

For the completeness of the post and after following what @Alex suggested.

I drop here the resulted code.
What you need to do before, is to create a job that executes the notebook you want.
Then you use the api to execute the job and get the result.

```
def _get_html_ouput(note_output: dict) -> str:
    data = note_output['views']
    # data = json.loads(note_output).get("views")
    output_file_names = set()
    for element in data:
        if element.get("type", None).lower() != "notebook":
            continue
        output_file = element.get("name")
        counter = 0
        while output_file in output_file_names:
            counter += 1
            output_file = "%s_%d" % (output_file, counter)
        output_file_names.add(output_file)
    return element.get("content", "")


def run_DQ_visualization_and_save_html(table: str, id_col: str, snapshot_col: str = 'ReferenceDate') -> None:
    time_executed = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").replace('/', '_')


    context = json.loads(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson())
    # context
    url = context['extraContext']['api_url']
    token = context['extraContext']['api_token']
    
    jobs_instance = Jobs.Jobs(url, token)  # initialize a jobs_instance
    runs_job_id = jobs_instance.runJob(53 ** ** ** ** ** *1, 'notebook',
                                                         {'id_col': id_col,
                                                          "snapshot_col": snapshot_col, 'table': table})
    
    print(
        f"{table}: Running Job. You can check status at the following link: https://adb-***868882***.***.azuredatabricks.net/?o=***687797****#job/*****54767")
    # check if the job is completed, then export the results.
    run_is_not_completed = True
    while run_is_not_completed:
        current_run = [run for run in jobs_instance.runsList('completed')['runs'] if
                       run['run_id'] == runs_job_id['run_id'] and run['number_in_job'] == runs_job_id['number_in_job']]
        if len(current_run) == 0:
            time.sleep(30)
        else:
            run_is_not_completed = False
            current_run = current_run[0]
            print(f"{table}: Run has been completed")
            print(f"{table}, Result state: " + current_run['state']['result_state'])
            print(f"{table}, You can check the resulted output in the following link: {current_run['run_page_url']}")
            note_output = jobs_instance.runsExport(runs_job_id['run_id'], 'CODE')  # use the job_id to export content
            notebook_result = _get_html_ouput(note_output)
            date_str = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
            save_output_path = f"abfss://****@****2.dfs.core.windows.netpath/DQ/html_files/{date_str}/{table}.html"
            dbutils.fs.put(save_output_path, notebook_result, overwrite=False)
            print(f'{table}, Result save at: {save_output_path}')
```

It is working fine. However, databricks recently put a limit of 10mbs on what you can export. If you have plots then you can easily exceeed that and it results with an error.
I don’t know why databricks added this size limit, it used to not be there and I could download much bigger html files.